# Be/Get offended

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I was practicing English online and a guy created a room and wrote "No Indian, Pakistani and Bangladeshi accent." He was an Indian himself and I said:

*"I'm not offended being from the subcontinent but some people even from other countries might **get/be offended**."*

He got a little offended and told me to leave and I said:

*"Please don't **be/get offended**. I'm just saying."*

Question- Please let me know the difference between 'be offended' and 'get offended.'

Comment: *Be* describes a current state; *get* describes the process of getting to a future state.

Comment: But "be" also works in a sentence like "Don't be offended if such-and-such happens," where it's the future we are concerned with. In Br.E "Please don't be offended" is considerate and placatory. "Please don't get offended" is less so, and might even sound disputatious, being one step down from "Don't start getting offended!"